# JumpStart Labs Event Manager: Syntax Error, unexpected ':'

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm working on the JumpStart Labs Event Manager, specifically the time/day of the week targeting, and I'm running into trouble. When I run the following code through Terminal, it gives me the following error [EDIT]:

```
austin-winslows-macbook-4:event_manager HypnoBoy$ ruby event_manager.rb
event_manager.rb:8: odd number list for Hash
...vent_attendees.csv', {headers: true, header_converters: :sym...
                          ^
event_manager.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
...vent_attendees.csv', {headers: true, header_converters: :sym...
                          ^
event_manager.rb:8: Can't assign to true
...ttendees.csv', {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol})
                          ^
event_manager.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
...ders: true, header_converters: :symbol})
```

I've posted my code below, and am looking for suggestions! Something about the syntax is obviously off, but I've followed the steps to the letter thus far, and haven't had any problems, so I'm not sure where to look anymore. Any help would be a great help, thanks!

```
require 'csv'
require 'sunlight/congress'
require 'erb'
require 'date'


Sunglight::Congress.api_key = "e179a6973728c4dd3fb1204283aaccb5"
contents = CSV.open('event_attendees.csv', {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol})


def clean_zipcode(zipcode)
zipcode.to_s.rjust(5,"0")[0..4]
end


def clean_phone(number)
number.to_s.rjust(10,"0")[0..4] 
end


def legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)
Sunglight::Congress::Legislator.by_zipcode(zipcode)
end


def peak_days
time = row[:regdate]
day_array = []
time.each { |t|
    array << Datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').wday }
end

def peak_hours
time = row[:regdate]
hr_array = []
time.each { |t|
        array << DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour }
array
end


def save_thanks_you_letters(id,form_letter)
Dir.mkdir("output") unless Dir.exists? "output"

filename = "output/thanks_#{id}.html"

File.open(filename, 'w') { |file|
    file.puts form_letter} 
end


puts "EventManager Initialized!"

template_letter = File.read "form_letter.erb"
erb_template = ERB.new template_letter

contents.each { |row|
id = row[0]

name = row[:first_name]

zipcode = clean_zipcode(row[:zipcode])

phone = clean_phone(row[:homephone]) 

legislators = legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)

form_letter = erb_template.result(binding)

save_thank_you_letters(id,form_letter)
}
```

Comment: give the full error stack

Comment: The problem might be that your arguments to :open are ambiguous to the ruby interpreter. Could you try writing them out explicitly, like this: contents = CSV.open('event_attendees.csv', {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol})

Answer (score 0):

from the doc [`CSV::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) you are using the construct :

```
open( filename, options = Hash.new )
```

So you line :

`contents = CSV.open 'event_attendees.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol` is wrong,as from 2nd parameter onward it is expecting a `Hash`. Thus change it to:

```
contents = CSV.open('event_attendees.csv', {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol})
```

Comment: In Ruby we're allowed to leave the braces off of a hash IF it's the last argument... but I agree this is a situation where it's better to be explicit

Comment: I made the suggested change, but now I'm receiving multiple errors. The edits are included above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I completed this exercise today. I didn't have to change the contents = CSV.open line. What caused the error for me was that the date was not formatted in the Excel file. I formatted that date column to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm in Excel. Also capitalization seemed to matter in the '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' string -- I used lowercase 'y'.

This is what my first time exercise looks like:

```
# Iteration: Time Targeting
contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol

regtimes = Array.new(25, 0)

contents.each do |row|

  reghour = DateTime.strptime(row[:regdate],'%m/%d/%y %H:%M').hour

  regtimes[reghour] += 1

end
```